# Getting Gmail Emails with Attachments usig Java IMAP

Tags: java, gmail, imap, email-attachments

I am trying to get emails from Gmail using Java. I using the java-gmail-imap library. When I try to get message.getContent(), it is always giving Inputstream. It doesn't provide me enough information to parse through the Part. My code looks like this. Please let me know what I am missing?

```
IMAPStore imapStore = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToImap(
            "imap.gmail.com", 993, email, token, false);

    Folder folder = imapStore.getFolder("Inbox");
    if (folder.isOpen()) {
        if ((folder.getMode() & Folder.READ_WRITE) != 0) {
            folder.close(false);
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Message[] messages = null;
    SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, lastDate);
    messages = folder.search(newerThan);


    FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
    fp.add("X-GM-MSGID");
    fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
    fp.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.X_GM_MSGID);
    //fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
    //fp.add(FetchProfileItem.FLAGS);
    //fp.add(FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
    // fp.add("X-mailer");
    folder.fetch(messages, fp); 

    for (Message message : messages) {

        if (message != null) {
            Object o = message.getContent();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                logger.info("Message content is string");
            } else if (o instanceof Multipart) {
                logger.info("Message content is multipart");
            } else if (o instanceof Message) {
                logger.info("Nested Message");
            } else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
                logger.info("Message content is inputstream");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** 
Issue is fixed by adding mailcap

CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(new com.google.code.javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mailcap")));